# Как быстро заполнить массив данными из файла/строки?

Tags: массивы, delphi, delphi-7

Есть массив

```
data: array [0..2999,0..2047] of byte;
```

и он заполняется данными из памяти открытого процесса:

```
for i:=0 to 2999 do
  ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, ptr(address), @data[i], 2048, temp);
```

Это происходит весьма быстро, за одну итерацию заполняется сразу 2048 элементов. Затем данные из этого массива сохраняются в файл в виде строки hex-значений, разделённых пробелом (в принципе формат сохранения не критичен, если его изменение поможет решить проблему).

Далее нужно открыть файл и заполнить его данными такой же массив, однако процесс затягивается на несколько минут, если делать это таким циклом:

```
for i:=0 to 2999 do
  for j:=0 to 2047 do
    data[i,j] := strtoint('$'+ copy(memo2.Text,(i*2048+j)*3,2));
```

Есть ли способ заполнять массив данными из файла/строки быстро, как это делает `ReadProcessMemory`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504705/delphi-copymemory-from-index тут есть пример(если я правильно понимаю что вы хотите заполнить, хотя читая текст примера - не уверен) =) если вы поясните что и во что копировать(с указанием типов данных) - возможно смогу подсказать точное решение

Comment: Как насчет TFileStream?Вообще медленное место на преобразовании строки и расчете я думаю

Comment: Зачем вам файл с hex значениями? Вам нужен человекочитабельный формат? И покажите процедуру сохранения в файл

Comment: Способ есть, если вы опишите что у вас в файле(подозреваю HEX), и что вам нужно в массиве(подозреваю бинарные данные) - то я смогу с большей вероятностью подсказать решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Если у вас файл это промежуточный формат хранения, который сами вы читать не собираетесь, то и пишите туда бинарные данные без всяких пребразований.

Comment: и уж точно не надо это в мемо загружать, чтобы заполнить массив. Там большую часть времени отрисовка мемо занимает. Либо файлстрим и пишите в файл бинарные. Либо поименуйте тип данных этого массива и сделайте `file of`, записав все сразу в файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На случай если вы просто хотите скинуть дамп массива в файл, а потом загрузить из него, то наиболее короткий путь это сделать будет, наверное, следующим:

```
type
    TData = array[0..2999, 0..2047] of byte;

var i,j: integer;
    x,y : TData;
    f : file of TData;
begin

    for i := 0 to high(x) do begin
        for j := 0 to 2047 do begin
            x[i][j] := Random(100);
        end;
    end;



    assign(f, 'd:\1.out');
    rewrite(f);
    write(f, x);


    reset(f);
    read(f, y);
    close(f);
end;
```

Сделайте из вашего массива тип данных, и объявите файл соответствующего типа.

Comment: Разве у вас нет ошибки? `write(f, x);` должен скинуть совсем не то что вы хотите =) пару лет не заглядывал в паскаль, но имхо `write(f, x[0]);` и то, сработает только при статическом массиве(т.е. как у вас в примере без отступлений в лево\право), двумерный динамический массив может быть(и скорее всего будет) ссылочным.
п.с. и таки FileStream\MemoryStream - будут предпочтительней

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков тут статический, поэтому и решение такое. если бряк поставить перед выходом и сравнить содержимое `x` и `y` то они совпадают. зы: делфи не трогал 5 лет уже

Comment: 1) После записи забыли закрыть файл. 2) Вместо `Close` предпочтительнее использовать `CloseFile`, чтобы случайно не закрыть форму. 3) По хорошему чтение/запись нужно обернуть в try finally

Comment: @AntonShchyrov `CloseFile` не закроет файл открытый с помощью assign, он для случая с использованием `FileOpen`

Comment: 1) а есть ли смысл закрывать, если я его сразу читаю, закрыть-открыть предлагаете? 2) это было консольное приложение 3) для демонстрации этого вполне достаточно, мы тут не обработку ошибок обсуждаем.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков 1) `Assign` не открывает файл. 2) Не путайте `CloseFile` и `FileClose`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov 1) согласен, не верно выразился, но я даже затрудняюсь сказать что он делает, хэндл создает? . 2) вполне вероятно что путаю, давно это было.

Comment: @teran Большое спасибо, способ с отдельным типом данных очень помог! А как быть, если в наличии несколько массивов разной размерности? Мне в принципе прокатит создание нескольких временных файлов под каждый тип данных в соответствии с массивами, но чисто для эстетики хочется это в одном файле организовать.

Comment: @SergeyL `TMyRecord = record ... x: array[....], y : array[.....] end;` и `file of TMyRecord`. В общем сложите что надо в структуру/запись, ее пишите в файл. В общем говоря, если у вас есть  нечто постоянной длины, то можно объявить это типом данных и писать в файл подобным образом.

Answer (score -1):

```
var 
  data: array [0..2999,0..2047] of byte;
  T:pbyte;
  FS : TMemoryStream;
  CH : byte[2];
begin
  T := @data;  //тут точно есть ошибка, не исправлено намерено
  FS:=TMemoryStream.Create();
  FS.loadFromFile('{FILE_NAME}'); //первая магия для скорости
  FS.position:=0;
  while(FS.position<FS.Size)
  begin
    FS.Read(CH,2);
    T^:=byte(HexToInt(CH)); //вторая магия
    inc(T);                 //третья магия
    (* в строке выше может быть ошибка(неверное увеличение указателя, 
       инкремент в паскале на указателях "должен" добавлять к указателю 
       ровно "размер" типа данных, в нашем случае один байт)
       тогда использовать такой вариант cardinal(T):=cardinal(T)+1; 
       строкой выше совершенно дикая магия, никогда так не делайте
       еще одно отступление от темы:
         cardinal(T):=cardinal(T)+1; - Этот код сработает только для 32х битных систем,
         верная запись NativeUInt(T):=NativeUInt(T)+1; 
         в D7 сработает и первый вариант
    *)
  end;  
end.
```

Грязные трюки которые тут использованы - использовать без полного понимания их работы не советую.
В коде намерено пропущено пара важных моментов, использовать этот код as is не выйдет, скорее всего вы получите неопределенное поведение или краш, код приведен лишь в качестве примера как "быстро" обрабатывать массивы данных.

Comment: Работа с указателями по вашему *"грязные трюки"* и *"магия"*? Вот уж удивительно!

Comment: @zed Работа с указателями вот так: `cardinal(T):=cardinal(T)+1;` грязные трюки. 
А вот так inc(T); - магия, т.к. не явно поведение(если не знать особенности которую я указал в коде) 
з.ы. для меня ни то ни то не является магией\грязным трюком, т.к. я точно понимаю что при этом происходит, но в делфи не принято так писать и это не с проста, если бы целью сообщения было показать грязные трюки - вы бы не увидели половины переменных был бы только массив и поток.

Comment: Если вы считаете, что в Delphi не принято увеличивать указатели при помощи `Inc`, то вы ошибаетесь. Это вполне нормальный код и инкремент смещает указатель ровно на столько байт, на сколько должен.

Comment: Я не оспариваю что он добавляет ровно столько сколько нужно **в обычных условиях**, я говорю что его поведение **не явно** для тех кто сталкивался с инкрементом(x++). но не всегда он добавляет столько сколько нужно, бывает надо обрабатывать данные по 3 байта, но для x86 обработка 3х байт(например xor) дороже чем обработка 4х байт, и выгоднее обработать 4 байта, и потом лишний байт отбросить. Надеюсь что вы не оспариваете утверждения что вот это `cardinal(T):=cardinal(T)+1;` грязный трюк?

Comment: Так обычно работают с нетипизированными указателями. Ничего грязного, обычная *pointer math*.

Comment: @zed ну и ладно, всегда считал это грязными хаками, если это нормальный код, чтож пусть будет нормальным кодом, просто ни разу не встречал в продакшене такого кода.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, в современных версиях удобнее использовать `T := PByte(T) + 1`, если `var T: Pointer`.

Comment: @Alekcvp спасибо за информацию, но на делфи я уже не пишу =)